# when optimising for a "location" based term, are links from the countries tld worth more?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, top-level-domains, local-seo

When optimizing for a term such as "bike shop london", do links from .co.uk and .com.uk domains carry more weight? ie. Would a link from a identical in every aspect apart from TLD be worth less in Google's eyes?

I know Google is putting a big emphasis on reliant thematic sites linking to you, but I wasn't sure whether this would have an effect? I'm referring to Google Search rather than Google Places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think having a TLD that is relevant to your location will help your local SEO efforts, a domain that contains the city in it would also dramatically help your situation such as 'bikeshoplondon.co.uk'.

As for gaining back links I think its more the content of the website that matters e.g. 'The london bike forum' will have information regarding questions about bikes, cycle routes and various other bycle related topics in London, if they were to link to you that would have more link juice than say 'The Paris bike forum'.

For more information on ranking for location based terms you might want to have a look at these links

http://searchengineland.com/local-seos-analyze-current-google-ranking-factors-124380

http://www.silkstream.net/blog/2011/10/understanding-how-to-rank-in-local-search.html

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where the search is happening. Google search results are localized according to which site you use (ie: google.com vs. google.co.uk)

As per your example, "the london bike shop" in London Connecticut would probably rank high on google.com. However "TheVeloBikeshop.co.uk" in london england would probably rank much lower on .com than if the search were from the local google.co.uk site.

As for the co.uk vs COM.uk I'm not really sure.

As always with SEO stuff, YMMV